After Ubuntu 24.04 upgrade multiple displays not working
Problem:
After upgrading from 23.10 to 24.04 multiple screens stopped working. If I plug in HDMI into laptop the monitor will say no signal and the screen stays dark. Powering on and shutting the lid with HDMI will make the screen work but then opening lid will make the laptop screen not work and stay dark (so it's not the issue with monitor/cable). Same thing happens with a dock station and 2 screens - powering on with lid closed will make the 2 monitors work (though they will mirror). Display settings do not show any settings for multiple displays.
What I've tried:

Disabling secure boot.
Trying many different drivers (nouveau, nvidia-driver-550, nvidia-driver- 535, nvidia-driver-545).
Changing nvidia to performance mode - this makes screen dark and not start up. Then have to open tty and switch profile to on demand.

Laptop - Dell Inc. Latitude 3520
xrandr:
None-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+

sudo lshw -C display:
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list fb
       configuration: depth=32 latency=0 mode=1920x1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff memory:6034000000-6034ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
  *-display
       description: 3D controller
       product: GP107M [GeForce MX350]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:600-5ff irq:202 memory:81000000-81ffffff memory:6020000000-602fffffff memory:6030000000-6031ffffff ioport:4000(size=128)
  *-graphics
       product: simpledrmdrmfb
       physical id: 4
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       capabilities: fb
       configuration: depth=32 resolution=1920,1080



Same problem by me. MSI Pulse 17 laptop

Although you stated installing "nvidia-driver-550" did not work for you, the same issue was resolved for me installing exactly this new driver:
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-550

Then a restart did fix the issue.

Since that driver does not work for the OP how does telling them to add it help?

@David it might help people like me who encounter the same symptoms (After upgrading from 23.10 to 24.04 multiple screens stopped working. If I plug in HDMI into laptop the monitor will say no signal and the screen stays dark.) and did not yet try to install nvidia-driver-550. Also as OP did not post a solution himself, he might have tried to install nvidia-driver-550, but simply forgot to restart his laptop.

@PSanetra command worked for me on a System 76 Thelio (with an RTX 3090) on Ubuntu Studio 24.04. Applied updates today, and my second monitor just stayed black. Installing nvidia-driver-550 fixed everything.

This worked for me on HP Zbook Fury 16 G9 with NVIDIA GA107GLM (RTX A1000). Thanks!

I was having the same issue and tried installing specific drivers until I came across this article https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/nvidia-drivers-installation
Running sudo ubuntu-drivers install with the auto-detection solved it for me. Though if that doesn't work hopefully the guide can help you with one of the alternative solutions.

Go to Software Updater -> Settings -> Additional Drivers -> Select an Nvidia Driver (I picked nvidia-driver-550-open) -> Apply changes
For some unknown reason the upgrade did not select the right driver for my system. I was able to make it work by selecting a different driver. Hope it helps

The automatic install for Nvidia drivers is not particularly transparent about its choice of drivers, so sometimes a smart manual choice of the proprietary graphics driver does the trick.

sudo ubuntu-drivers install worked for me just fine.
but i did try sudo apt install nvidia-driver-550 first but didn't do the trick for me.

This has already been written in other answers.

I did everything everyone mentioned but it didn't work straightforward. So here's what I did and it magically fixed the problem.
Search for driver in your applications list in ubuntu 24 and open Additional Drivers
Here on this page select the option xserver-xorg-video-nouveau and click on Apply Changes
When it's done, reboot, come back to Additional Drivers and pick first option, nvidia-driver-535
Just like this image:


My setup is A Dell Inspiron 15 7000 Gaming.
My chosen nvidea driver was the following:
xorg x server nouveau display driver

I just changed to:
NVIDEA driver metapackage from nvidea-driver-550 (propietary, tested)

and it worked just fine.
When I was with Ubuntu 22.04 I literally tried everything, without success, but now in Ubuntu 24.04 it worked!

I ended up using both of my graphics cards.  Not having just NVIDIA or Intel. I added these sections to my xorg.conf, after backing up the other config.  Get your BusIDs from
lspci -vnn | grep -A 12 VGA

Then backup conf, and edit
sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.bak
sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf

add
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "Intel"
    Screen 1 "NVIDIA" RightOf "Intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "Intel"
    Driver "modesetting"
    BusID "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "NVIDIA"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

then
sudo systemctl restart gdm

now both displays work fine.  and sudo dmesg | grep i915 and nvidia-smi both show the GPUs responsible for displays.  NVIDIA also still PRIME and in performance mode, so should be good for modelling too. Still to test it out.
If that was an answer some people find helpful.   Enjoy

Try this Mutter 46.1 patch => https://askubuntu.com/a/1512647/1761962
cf) original mutter change log info => https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/blob/main/NEWS

I tried this, and my mutter version now shows 46.1, but it didn't solve the problem. Now, when I plug in two monitors, they're detected by my laptop (they show up in the display settings), but the screens are just blank black. (This is 13th gen Intel mobile, integrated graphics.)

My setup consists of a 4K external monitor connected to a laptop. Since upgrading to 24.04, the virtual screen resolution on the external monitor is larger than the physical resolution, resulting in unusable scaling.
While fractional scaling was previously enabled, adjusting the scale factor had no effect on the external display.
Applying the Mutter 46.1 patch (as suggested by @kvmb11) resolved the virtual vs. physical screen size mismatch. However, this disabled fractional scaling functionality. Now, even if I turn fractional scaling "on," I can no longer adjust the scaling factor like before.

I had exactly the same issue but after I disable the fast boot on my Intel NUC. Both monitors are now displayed normally. I'm glad that I don't have to reinstall Ubuntu.

disabling fast boot didnt work for me on Lenovo IdeaPad Gaming 3

Try this very nuclear solution. It worked for me using nvidia-driver-550 on my custom laptop that uses an older GPU and is running Ubuntu 24.04 LTS.
# Remove old Nvidia things
sudo apt-get purge ‘^nvidia-.*’ 
sudo apt-get autoremove 
sudo apt-get autoclean 
sudo rm /var/crash/nvidia-dkms-545.0.crash # Look for your very own crashy things

# Reinstall dependency things
sudo apt-get install build-essential dkms linux-headers-$(uname -r) 
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev libglvnd-dev pkg-config

# Add Nvidia repos
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa 
sudo apt-get update

# Install Nvidia drivers
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-5XX # Mine was 550, yours may be different

# Update Intramfs and reboot
sudo update-initramfs -u 
sudo reboot

That did it for me, but I knew which Nvidia driver was the "good one" when I did this. For you, you may need to see which drivers are installed using "Software & Updates > Additional Drivers" ... If there's a long list of drivers, obliterate them and simplify the configuration on your laptop.
Good luck!

Here’s the step-by-step process that fixed the issue for me:

Install the NVIDIA Driver open a terminal and run the following
command to :sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-560

Select the NVIDIA Driver in Software & Updates Open Software &
Updates from the application menu. Go to the additional drivers tab.
Select the option: "NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-560
(proprietary)". Click apply changes and reboot your system.

Disable secure boot in BIOS:
During boot, enter your BIOS/UEFI settings locate the secure boot
option and disable it. Save the changes and exit the BIOS.


I hope this work for you too!

I got an N: Unable to locate package nvidia-driver-560 error message in Ubuntu 24.04.

Did you check the recommended driver version for your GPU?

When I installed Ubuntu 24.04 I selected the option to install 3rd party codecs and proprietary drivers. When this option is selected the Ubuntu installer selects and installs the recommended proprietary graphics automatically without any additional user intervention required.

The whole conversation from this question helped me resolve a black screen issue with my second monitor about a month ago when I upgraded Ubuntu 22.04 -> 23.04. However, I recently upgraded my system again, and now my second screen has stopped working again.
To fix the issue I had to:

Update Nvidia driver ->
sudo apt update and sudo apt install nvidia-driver-550
Log Out.
In the Login screen in the bottom right corner click on Settings icon.
Change session to Ubuntu. You will see two options 1.Ubuntu and 2.Ubuntu with Wayland.

I hope this can help someone, so you won't spend a month using integrated GPU instead of more powerful one :)

I have undeleted your answer but it is not clear to me which answer is "This post". Please link it into your answer...
